# MSSQL multiple row depletion to multiple row

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two tables with following value

**Table 1**

```
OrderNo  ItemID   OrderQty
============================
O01      1         8
O02      1         6
O03      1         3
```

**Table 2**

```
PackNo   ItemID   PackQty
=============================
P01      1         8
P02      1         7
```

This is what i want to achieve

```
ItemID    OrderNo   OrderQty    PackNo     PackQty
===================================================
1         O01        8           P01         8
1         O02        6           P02         6
1         O03        3           P02         1
```

which distributing pack qty to order qty order by qty desc

is there any SQL query can achieve this goal?

any help would be appreciated
thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see how you get these results from this sample data. Specifically the third line of your results - why does O03 get joined to a row with P02?

Comment: Yes, but can you use a stored proc ? that would be the easiest way.

Comment: Give us the logic for splitting 7 into 1 and 6.

Comment: Are you trying to keep tabs on incoming\outgoing stock? So you have two packs, one of 8 and one of 7 - the first one (8 units) was depleted by OrderNo 001, and therefore OrderNo 002 takes 6 from the next pack (02), and the final OrderNo 003 can only take one final unit from Pack 02, which menas you're one short? That's the closest thing to logic that I can see here...

Comment: This is a variation of "keeping a running remaining balance in SQL Server"  and if you google that phrase you will find examples.